# Why can't gdb evaulate functions when !=/== and &&/|| are combined in an expression?

Tags: c++, gdb

It may be that the difficulty I'm having in describing my problem is the reason I can't find anyone else with an instance of it. I am using gdb 7.4-2012.04.

It seems at the least that any expression involving both !=/== and &&/|| for vectors or vector iterators will fail to evaluate in gdb with the following error:

Cannot access memory at address 0x0

Here's a test case, followed by my compilation line and tests:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef char GUID[32];

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    vector<int> vec;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
    for (vector<int>::iterator vecIter=vec.begin(); vecIter!=vec.end(); vecIter++){
        int i=0;//Just need a line gdb will recognize for a breakpoint.
    }
    cout << vec[0] << endl;//g++ needs to include operator[] in the binary for this to work.
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a snippet of the tests I performed:

```
user@comp$ g++ -g -O0 any_test.cpp
user@comp$ gdb a.out
(gdb) b 16
(gdb) r
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe288) at any_test.cpp:16
16          int i=0;//Just need a line gdb will recognize for a breakpoint.
(gdb) p *vecIter == vec[1] or *vecIter == vec[2]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

The original useful statement does not work. Let's reduce a bit and find the problem.

```
(gdb) p vec[1] or *vecIter == vec[2]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) p vec[1] or *vecIter
$1 = true
(gdb) p 1 or *vecIter == vec[2]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

Looks like the problem is '==' after 'or'. Is this the same with other operators?

```
(gdb) p 1 and *vecIter == vec[2]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) p 1 and *vecIter != vec[2]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

That's a resounding yes. What if I pull out all the functions for gdb? Just let it dereference and compare ints?

```
(gdb) p 1 or *vecIter._M_current == vec._M_impl._M_start[1]
$2 = true
```

Ok, let's check some combinations of derefs and functions to make sure it's not just one of these types that causes the problem:

```
(gdb) p 1 or *vecIter._M_current == *vecIter
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) p 1 or vec._M_impl._M_start[1] == vec[1]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

As you can see, the problem is not specifically the vector or its iterator. Any operator (function) called on either one will trigger this issue if inserted after &&/||, and on either side of an ==/!=.

EDIT: forgot a question again. My question is this:
Why do I get "Cannot access memory at address 0x0" in the line "p *vecIter == vec[1] or *vecIter == vec[2]"?

Comment: Please let me know if the above information is insufficient to reproduce the stated behaviour.

Comment: "p  *vecIter == vec[1] or 1" is working. But not "p 1 or *vecIter == vec[1]" , looks like a bug :)

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but I can definitely reproduce it with GDB 7.8 on 64 bit RHEL 5. Bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in functions that return references.  Here's a minimal example:

```
int& g() { static int i; return i; }
int main() {}
```

The same problem is exhibited (I'm using gdb 7.8.1):

```
(gdb) p 0 || +g()
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

A workaround is to convert the reference to a pointer and indirect it:

```
(gdb) p 0 || +*&g()
$1 = true
```

Filed a bug: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17904

Answer (score 0):

The order of evaluating "*vecIter == vec[1]" is evaluating *vecIter first, if true then skip evaluating vec[1] and the whole statement is true; and if false then evaluate vec[1]. The root cause here is that vecIter pointing to NULL memory, which is inaccessible, that *vecIter could not even be evaluated. Therefore gdb print out the "memory access" error.

same reason for other print statements of same error